# How can I get pytesseract to recognize this low resolution image?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Anyone have any pointers on how to get pytesseract to recognize this low resolution image?:
[image]

Unfortunately I wont be able to use a higher resolution image in this case.
Pytesseract is having no luck finding the '29' in this image.
I've tried preprocessing the image by changing to grayscale, changing to black and white, and inverting the image (using this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADV-AjAXHdc&list=PL2VXyKi-KpYuTAZz__9KVl1jQz74bDG7i&index=4) and nothing has worked to get Pytesseract to find the '29' value.
here are some of the preprocessed images I have attempted:[image][image][image]

Anyone have any advice on how to use pytesseract to find the value from low resolution images like this?